# How to reduce the width of all elements?

Tags: html, psd

I'm trying to convert a psd mockup file into html & css, but the width of page is 1700 px, too big to be rendered without horizontal scrollbars. So I want to limit the width or to set a percentage value for it, but doing so I'd have to change sizes of all the elements.

Comment: So it means your PSD is wrongly drawn. Standard website is 1200px wide max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Justinas says, you should fit your site to maximum 1200px, so you need do redo your design.

I can recommend [960 grid system](http://960.gs/). All the important things should be within 960px.